# How to get an area Latlong geometry directly from google map?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, spatial-database, google-earth, latitude-longitude

I am new to field of GIS.

I need to know that do we have an option of getting latlong of a building that we see in google earth or any Point of Interest areas.

Something like i create & drag over an area or road(on google map or google earth) and its respective geometrical shape(with Latlong information) gets saved in database or gets popped up.

Is there any tool which does that?

I believe this is what GIS Data Vendors use to create their data.

How can i get geometries of a buildings in a locality boundary or district boundary in few minutes,is it possible?

Comment: In Google Maps you can simply right-click a location and select "What's here?" You'll be presented with a popup at the bottom of the page that includes a Latitude Longitude coordinate pair, among other things.

Comment: Thanks but i was more concerned about Polygon building areas with exact latlong geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Google Earth Pro** (this is free now)

Use the Measure Tool (ruler)

Draw around your rooftop building as polygon

`save -> Polygon Measure` goes to the 'Temporary Places' in the Left Table

Right Click 'copy' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)

Using Notepad++
Paste as XML
Coordinates are found in Polygon Tag as LinearRing Coordinates

[image]

Comment: Thanks,It was helpful but unfortunately does not meet my exact requirement;creating polygon by ruler over every building to get their latlong is a tedious and giant task.If i need all building polygon geometries of a locality or ward or district,how can i do it fast with exact geometry data being fetched,there must be a way which i being unexperienced is not aware of.I have seen may GIS Data Vendors create and sell these data,though i am not aware how much they charge for it.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Earth, the yellow thumbtack tool is your 'placemark' tool you'll notice that when you click on that tool you get a yellow placemark icon in your window with an active boundary border around it. You can click the active placemark and drag it to where your building is, you will notice that as you do so, the recorded coordinates for your placemark change as well. Once your placemark is where you need it, you can click 'ok' in your active window and it will log the coordinates for that placemark.

You can do this as many times as needed and save additional location data as you save the various placemarks, for instance renaming them as building 1, building 2, etc. or whatever you need.

From there you can right click your 'My Places' layer in your table of contents and select the 'save place as' option. The default file type is a .kml file which is the primary GIS file type for Google Earth and can be imported into most other GIS software that I know of. The lat long data is preserved in the layer along with any unique naming convention that you assigned.

If importing into ArcMap however, you'll probably have to build new x,y fields in table view and calculate geometry to get the locations back into your attributes.

You can perform these same actions for the 'add polygon' tool and 'new path' tool for creating various layers. You can also download Google Earth Pro for free now which opens up additional functionality for importing/exporting various other GIS filetypes.

When you first download Google Earth Pro, you should see options for obtaining the licence and username, in a sense I think you end up linking it to your Google+ account or .gmail if you have one, or they walk you through creating one. Then they email you the licence keycode and you copy it over.

In order to automate your data, you could try importing a table into your 'my places' as long as the table has either addresses or lat/long for the buildings in it already. You go to 'file', 'open' and click the filetype drop down to all files, which will allow you to find a .txt file. You have a lot of options here, but I find that saving my spreadsheet to a .txt (tab deliminated) works well. From there, the import wizard in Google Earth will ask you which fields are your lat/long fields. If you have lat/long, simply tell Google Earth Pro which fields to look at. Once you've done that it should plot them for you.

If you have addresses instead, you check the box that says you don't have lat/long and it will take you to the addressing part of the wizard. From here, tell it if you have the entire address in one field or in multiples and plug in the necessary data. Again, when you complete the wizard it should plot it for you as best it can and then you can follow the process to export your 'my places' into a .kml

Comment: Thanks Joshua for the detailed Information.After your answer i downloaded Google Pro free and exploring other options. Also i was looking for a way to automate it or is there any tool which does it in bulk? I mean for highlighting a building of a particular area or POI moving over each building one by one is very long and tedious process so can we achieve it with less effort? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the info you asked

Comment: Note: If you use Google Earth Pro (There are Measure Tools) that show lat & lng's for your lines/area